# 値に変化が起きたときの値を、コンソールにログを出力するには？

Tags: ios, objective-c

現在、Buttonを押すと値を表示しています。
表示をButtonを押さずとも更新して表示し、その値をコンソールにログを出力するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

//アンテナバー
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAntennaBar;
//RSSI
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelRssi;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)buttonGetValue:(id)sender {
    self.labelAntennaBar.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", [self antennaBar]];
    self.labelRssi.text        = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zd", [self radioRssi]];
}


#pragma mark - Status bar

- (NSInteger )antennaBar {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"]
                          valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    return  [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthBars"] intValue];
}

- (NSInteger )radioRssi {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"]
                          valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    NSString *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    return  [[dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"signalStrengthRaw"] intValue];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVO (Key-Value Observing)を使うのがいいと思います。具体的には下記のように`UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView`のインスタンスに対して、それぞれ`signalStrengthBars`と`signalStrengthRaw`のプロパティの変化を監視します。監視は`viewDidLoad`あたりで登録するといいです。

監視対象のプロパティの値が変化すると`- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`が呼ばれますのでその中でラベルに値を設定します。

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"] subviews];
    UIView *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarSignalStrengthItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }

    [dataNetworkItemView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"signalStrengthBars" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [dataNetworkItemView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"signalStrengthRaw" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(nullable NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(nullable id)object change:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)change context:(nullable void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"signalStrengthBars"]) {
        self.labelAntennaBar.text  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]];
    }
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"signalStrengthRaw"]) {
        self.labelRssi.text        = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]];
    }
}
```